# How to get performance of a program over multiple invocations?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to check the performance of a program. I have the following program:

```
/* stdlibrary_writer.c ‐ write 400,000 characters with fprintf */
#include <stdio.h>
#define OUTPUTNAME "fprint.out"
main()
{
  long i;
  FILE *fp;
  if ((fp=fopen(OUTPUTNAME,"w")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Can't open %s. Bye.\n",OUTPUTNAME);
    exit(1);
  }
  for (i=0; i<400000; i++) { /* write 400,000 Xs with fprintf */
    if (fprintf(fp,"X") < 1) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Can't write. Bye\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  exit(0);
}
```

I want to time this program over 10 consecutive invocations. How can I do that?
I want to use Unix's `/usr/bin/time` command to time the program.

Comment: On linux use `$ time fprint.out`

Comment: So...... run it with `time`. What's the question here?

Comment: Just FYI, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main()` in explicit .form.

Comment: @SouravGhosh My question is how to time it over 10 consecutive invocations?

Comment: @LindaSu I never tried to answer your question, it was a suggestion to improve the code. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you need to compile your program. For benchmarking ask for compiler [optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) using `-O2`, e.g.

```
 gcc -Wall -O2 -g stdlibrary_writer.c -o stdlibrary_writer
```

You could time a shell loop like

```
 time for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do ./stdlibrary_writer ; done
```

but actually you probably should measure 10 times then compute the average (& min and max), e.g.

```
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do echo round $i;  time  ./stdlibrary_writer ; done
```

Notice that you could automate the computation of average, min and max by piping the above command into some [awk(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html) script (that you should write yourself).

BTW, use `perror`, or `strerror(errno)`, or `%m` in GNU [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), to handle errors, e.g.

```
if ((fp=fopen(OUTPUTNAME,"w")) == NULL) {
 perror(OUTPUTNAME);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

or

```
if ((fp=fopen(OUTPUTNAME,"w")) == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr,"Can't open %s. (%s), Bye.\n",
          OUTPUTNAME, strerror(errno));
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

or

```
if ((fp=fopen(OUTPUTNAME,"w")) == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr,"Can't open %s. (%m), Bye.\n",
          OUTPUTNAME);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

You need to read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the program and then use time when executing it to know it's performance like following,

```
$ gcc stdlibrary_writer.c -o stdlibrary_writer.o

$ time ./stdlibrary_writer.o
```

For 10 consecutive time performance check you need to run it into a loop like this,

```
c=1
while [ $c -le 10 ]
do
    time ./stdlibrary_writer.o
    (( c++ ))
done
```

Comment: My question is how to time it over 10 consecutive invocations?

Comment: well you have to repeat the same method which i had given, use 10 consecutive `time` along with your executable file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. How to use 10 consecutive time along with your executable file. Sorry, I'm new to linux. Could you please elaborate your explanation?

Comment: Everytime you running your executable such as `stdlibrary_writer.o` add the `time` then you will find performance of each time, and for 10 consecutive time you need to use a loop in shellscript and run the `time ./stdlibrary_writer.o` command into it.

Comment: Wrong to name an executable `stdlibrary_writer.o`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i just choose arbitrarily to answer his/her question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking how much time is consumed in executing your program from Unix shell, make use of Linux time as below,

```
time ./a.out 

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Secondly if you want time took in executing number of statements in the program code (C) try making use of [gettimeofday()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) as below,

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval  tv1, tv2;
gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
/* Program code to execute here */
gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
printf("Time taken in execution = %f seconds\n",
   (double) (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000 +
   (double) (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec));
```

Comment: Don't use `gettimeofday()`, among other things, it's not monotonic.  Use `clock_gettime()`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp My question is how to time it over 10 consecutive invocations?